# Firefox Developer version and firebug 3.0 failed install of add-on

Tags: firefox, firebug

I have developer version installed (44.0a2) with firebug 2.0.13 plugin.  When I right-click on the webpage and select "inspect element with firebug" I get a pop-up asking me to install firebug 3.0 beta.  when I click "install and restart" I get an error message saying the install of firebug 3.0 failed.

When I try to install firebug 3.0 manually - `firebug-3.0.0-beta.1.xpi` I get a failed install due to add-on not verified.  I am getting the firebug 3.0 xpi from https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/3.0/

Can anyone help with how to install firebug 3.0 with the developer version of firefox?

Comment: Firebug devs are in the process of rewriting from the ground up, Next Firebug generation will be built on top of the native Firefox developer tools  https://github.com/firebug/firebug.next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem today. It is because by default firefox is not allowing unsigned plugins, which firebug 3 is because it is still beta.

To disable extensioning signing
type about:config in the address bar

- search for xpinstall.signatures.required
- Right click and toggle it to false
- This should allow it to install.

The alternative is disabling multiprocess firefox so that firebug 2 can 
still work. This can be done by disabling multiprocess firefox in the settings menu.

Comment: Disabling **xpinstall.signatures.required** did not work for me. Firefox 50.1.0